# Centering a DIV with CSS

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to center a div in the exact center of the page with CSS, now before you guys actually suggest me some of the google results, I know they don't work

This one for example:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

This doesn't center a div, it centers it + the width + the height. How can I exactly center it in the middle? Here is my div:

```
<div class="notification-instance ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="width:33.333333333333336%;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="draggable panel panel-pink">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #B00049">
            Panel Title
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also cannot use col-md with bootstrap so that's out of the queston.
I also don't know the width or height of my div as it's passed via a parametrer

Comment: you could do the old fashioned trick here of `margin-left:auto;` `margin-right:auto;` Though Im pretty sure if you're using bootstrap you can simply use the offset classes.

Comment: just add transfom:translate(-50%,-50%); to your css

Answer (score 3):

Use `transform:translate(-50%,-50%);`

```html
<div class="notification-instance ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="width:33.333333333333336%;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);background:#fff;">
    <div class="draggable panel panel-pink">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #B00049">
            Panel Title
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mattonit/erf1ff73/)

Comment: Explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982135/why-does-left-50-transform-translatex-50-horizontally-center-an-element

Comment: could you please show us the demo of this?

Comment: Thank you, this is working but it messes up my draggable event. When I try and drag my div it jumps out of position?

Comment: @LiamSavage how do you expect an element to be perfectly centered and draggable?