# Positioning a div relative to its vertical centre

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, positioning

I have a welcome message which needs its centre to be positioned at 25% from the top of the window. Because it could be any number of lines long it needs to be positioned using its vertical centre. Here is what I have currently.

```
.welcomeMessage {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  top: 25%;
}
```

I have tried using display: inline-block and display: flex with vertical-align: middle but neither position the div relative to its vertical centre. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Desired positioning:
[image: Desired positioning]
Current positioning:
[image]

Comment: I have edited my answer with both positioning (the one you currently have and the corrected one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet bellow I have two elements, both set to `position:absolute` with `top: 25%` and `left: 50%` .

- `.element` as [`transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982135/why-does-left-50-transform-translatex-50-horizontally-center-an-element) that allows him to center vertically and horizontally **"exactly"** at 25% of the page dimensions (height, width). Because unlike [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top) and [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/left), the [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property is based on the size of the target element. So the percentage you set refers to the size of the bounding box of the target.
- `.other` in the other hand doesn't have a `transform` rule so it's not positioned like you wanted it to be, its top border sits at 25%

```css
.element,
.other {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
}

.element {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: green;
}

.other {
  color: red;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">I'm at 25% middle</div>
<div class="other">I'm not at 25% middle</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform:translate(-50%);`

`margin: auto;` does not work with `inline-block` elements, so you need to add `left:50%` to make it horizontally center.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.welcomeMessage {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  left:50%;
  width: 60%;
  top: 25%;
  transform:translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="welcomeMessage">Welcome Message</div>
```

Comment: why -75% and not -50%?

Comment: @ManuelOtto Corrected

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work. I defined the size for `h1` as 2em and calculate the top position, decreasing 25% with half the font size.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgray;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.welcomeMessage {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  top: calc(25% - 1em)
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<h1 class="welcomeMessage">Welcome</h1>
```